# JQuery show() and hide() within the same loop

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I have the following piece of code, I need to show or hide the panels. My question is, the show() works on alternative clicks only.

```
var allPanels = $(".panel");
allPanels.hide(2000);
allPanels.show();
```

I would like to know the reason why show() does not work consistently.

Comment: I figured that if I use allPanels.hide(2000); and allPanels.show(1000); or allPanels.show(2000); it works but not if allPanels.show();

Comment: You're using animation so you can shot after they are hidden `allPanels.hide(2000, function() { $(this).show() });`

Comment: Thanks Alon and @Rana - I guess I was not clear enough. I wanted to know why show() was not able to display the elements unless show(1000) was called. Nevertheless, thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not working because you set time in `.hide(2000)`. You have to write in following way::

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel" >This is a DIV</div>
<button type="button" class="buttonClick" >Click me</button>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $(document).on('click', '.buttonClick', function () {
        var allPanels = $(".panel");
        allPanels.hide(2000, function(){
            allPanels.show();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @Sujit Please accept the answer if it is right for helping others.

Answer (score 0):

an easier approach would be to **.stop()** the current animation just before you start another one.

```
var allPanels = $(".panel");
allPanels.hide(2000);
allPanels.stop().show();
```

this way you won't have to place the code in the callback.
do notice though, doing this will explicitly pause the animation ignoring its current state.

Comment: allPanels.stop().show(); did not work, threw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

When I removed the animation timing from the

```
var allPanels = $(".panel");
allPanels.hide(2000);
allPanels.stop().show();
```

Changed to

```
var allPanels = $(".panel");
allPanels.hide();
allPanels.stop().show();`enter code here`
```

it started working. Hide and Show works seamlessly. Thanks. But can anyone say why hide and show with timing does not work.